# Were Anne Elisabeth Stengl's project under her pseudonym more financially successful?

Tags: anne-elisabeth-stengl, sylvia-mercedes, the-venatrix-chronicles

Follow-up to: [Did Anne Elisabeth Stengl ever write a book under a pen name like she announced that she would? If so, what was it?](https://literature.stackexchange.com/questions/5225/did-anne-elisabeth-stengl-ever-write-a-book-under-a-pen-name-like-she-announced)

Anne Elisabeth Stengl [indicated](https://www.lifeisstory.com/podcast/tales-of-goldstone-wood-remembered-a-conversation-with-sylvia-mercedes-anne-elisabeth-stengl/) in several sources that part of the reason she was forced to "give up on" the Tales of Goldstone Wood was the limited financial success of the series. She since started writing under a new penname (Sylvia Mercedes), where she wrote (among other things) the Venatrix Chronicles.

Have those projects (in particular, the Venatrix Chronicles) been more financially successful?